# Percision loss when converting float to string

Tags: python

Lets assume a Customer wants to know a price of a product, so I perform a Database query, and get the value 95 (as int) representing the value in cents. Now I want to tell the customer the price in euros, so I do that:

```
    print("Price: " + format(price/100, ".2f") + "EUR")
```

What I get printed is:

```
    Price: 0.00EUR
```

Why and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Convert your variable float (now result of `price / 100` is integer). For example, `print("Price: " + format(price/100.0, ".2f") + "EUR")`.

Comment: When it comes to money, it's best to use `Decimal`: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 2):

You need your output to be a float. Try dividing by 100.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast to float by doing `price = float(whatever)` before the string format. If the numerator or denominator is a float, then the result will be also. If both are integers result will be integer.

Comment: This answer implies that you can do `price = float(price/100)`, which is incorrect.

Comment: No. The answer implies that you can cast ``price`` to float before the string format, when he gets ``price``.

But I edited the answer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This happens since `price` and `100` are both `int`s - and if you do any operations on `int`s, the result will be an `int`. When you do `price/100`, you get `0.95` floored to an `int` i.e. `0` and then `format (0, ".2f")` gives you `0.00`. What you need to do is convert `price` to a `float` before you do any operations on it, as in `format(float(price)/100, ".2f")` or you can just divide by a float `100.0` instead, as in `format(price/100.0, ".2f")` to fix this.